# CudaEvent timing of Kernel launch

Tags: cuda, profiling

I'm trying to interpret some timings I did using CudaEvents, does timing kernel execution via CudaEvents also include the overhead time for kernel launch?

Unfortunately I no longer have access to a Cuda compatible GPU to do any tests on.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly captures *some* kind of overhead, based on my experiments.

I think it should be clear that if the kernel is bracketed by other synchronous activity, then the CPU overhead *must* be included, as the CPU overhead separates the previous activity from the kernel launch:

```
cudaEventRecord(start);
cudaMemcpy(...);         // cudaMemcpy 1
my_kernel<<<...>>>(...);
cudaMemcpy(...);
cudaEventRecord(stop);
```

Certainly it seems obvious to me that the timing depicted above *must* capture the CPU overhead between cudaMemcpy 1 and the kernel call (along with various other time contributions not due to the kernel itself.)

So the less obvious case is when the kernel is alone or is bracketed by other async calls:

```
cudaEventRecord(start);
my_kernel<<<...>>>(...);
cudaEventRecord(stop);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
```

Based on my testing of the above pattern, and with an empty kernel:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(){
  }
```

I observe timings on linux of at least several microseconds, and this is quite a bit longer than the time required to execute the two instructions in my empty kernel:

```
            Function : _Z8mykernelv
    /*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
    /*0008*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
```

Therefore I claim that some sort of execution set-up overhead is being captured by the `cudaEvent` system.  If someone wants to claim that this overhead is *not* CPU overhead, but something else, so be it.

My claim is that some form of overhead is captured, and I see no reason not to refer to it as CPU overhead.  Furthermore, with typical `cudaEvent` timing that includes a `cudaEventSynchronize()` immediately following the `stop` marker, it seems clear that the host thread will be blocked for at least the duration captured by the `cudaEvent` system between the `start` and `stop` markers, therefore I see no reason in that case not to refer to it as CPU overhead.

Comment: Doesn't the "overhead capture" depend on whether you use the default stream or not?